# Почему выдает ошибку о несовпадении типов и почему программа выдает неправильный результат?

Tags: php, ооп

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     class Dog {
         private $age;
         private $weight;
         private $color;

         public function setAge(int $yrs) {$age = $yrs;}
         public function setWeight(double $kg) {$weight = $kg;}
         public function setColor(string $clr) {$color = $clr;}

         public function getAge() {return $age;}
         public function getWeight() {return $weight;}
         public function getColor() {return $color;}

         public function Bark() {echo "ГАВ! ГАВ!<br>";}
     }

     $haski = new Dog();

     $haski->setAge(3);
     $haski->setWeight(5.5);
     $haski->setColor("коричневого");

     echo "Данные о собаке Хаски:<br>";

     echo "Её возраст составляет " . $haski->getAge() . " год(а/лет).<br>";
     echo "Её вес составляет " . $haski->getWeight() . "кг.<br>";
     echo "Она " . $haski->getColor() . " цвета.<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dog::setWeight() must be an instance of double, float given, called in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\project47 (ООП 1).php on line 30 and defined in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\project47 (ООП 1).php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\project47 (ООП 1).php(30): Dog->setWeight(5.5) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\project47 (ООП 1).php on line 17

"Аргумент 1 отданный в Dog::setWeight() должен быть представлением double, но был передан float". Что-то я вообще не понял. 5.5 может быть как double, так и float. Почему PHP говорит, что типы не совпадают? Если убрать из определения функции setWeight указание типа "double", то программа будет работать без синтаксических ошибок, но вылезают очень странные ошибки другого рода. Геттеры либо не отдают значения, либо отдают, но других переменных

Вместо такого вывода
Данные о собаке хаски:
Её возраст составляет 3 год(а/лет).
Её вес составляет 5.5 кг.
Она коричневого цвета.

Выводит вот эту ерунду:
Данные о собаке Хаски:
Её возраст составляет коричневого год(а/лет).
Её вес составляет коричневого кг.
Она коричневого цвета.

Что не так, почему не работает? Как исправить?
1) Почему выдается ошибка о не совпадении типов если указать тип параметра в функции setWeight double
2) И почему возвращаются некорректные данные из геттеров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** `double` не входит в список допустимых [типов](https://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

**2** При использовании что сеттеров, что геттеров - забываете про [область видимости](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php) объявленных переменных.

```
public function setWeight(float $kg) {
  $this->weight = $kg;
}
public function getWeight() {
  return $this->weight;
}
```